# The given key was not present in the dictionary while filling dataadapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, dataadapter

The given key was not present in the dictionary.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:
>   The given key was not present in the dictionary.

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Database=gransells; User ID=root; Password=PASSWORD;");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select description from product where productId=1", con);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: The stack Trace is approximately 95% of the information carried by an Exception. And this message *explicitly* tells you to look at it. You also did not specify the line this happens, so we can only asume `adapter.Fill(ds);`

Comment: happening at adapter.Fill(ds);

Answer (score 0):

You have the primary key in the table which you are setting but not retrieving..Use that primary key in the select statement.